# Animate opacity and delay transition CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a series of `DIVS`, I want `DIV 1` & `DIV 3` to fade out and then `DIV 2` and `DIV 4` to slide left to take their place, 1 second after the fade.  So far I have gotten them to fade out but I cannot figure out how to delay the sliding. Follows is my CSS, ignore the lack of vendor prefixes for this question please.

```
.slide-show{
  -webkit-animation: fadeShow 0.25s 1 normal forwards ease-out;
  animation: fadeShow 0.25s 1 normal forwards ease-out;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slide-hide{
  -webkit-animation: fadeHide 0.25s 1 normal forwards ease-out;
  animation: fadeHide 0.25s 1 normal forwards ease-out;

  //I need the following to be delayed for 1 second
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes fadeHide{
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}


@keyframes fadeShow{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: try jquery it will save you time

Comment: I cannot use jQuery, sorry

Comment: please provide HTML too

Comment: @user1876246 Did my recommended approach with the `animation-delay` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `animation-delay` or just place the delay in the animation shorthand. The order of the animation shorthand values doesn't matter except when using both duration and delay. Duration comes first then delay: `animation: valueA valueB DURATION DELAY valueC ...;`